# I have a weird issue with hash:sha512(works perfectly, except when i tried logging in with wrong password

Tags: php

session_start();

```
if(isset($_SESSION['logged'])){
    header('Location: esm_questionnaire.php');
}
if(isset($_POST['utilisateur'])&&isset($_POST['motdepasse'])){
    $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    mysql_select_db('esm_quiz', $con);
    $datID = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['utilisateur']);
    $datPASS = $_POST['motdepasse'];
    $datPASS = hash(sha512, $datPASS);
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM esm_sujets WHERE code_exp = '$datID'";
    $result = mysql_query($SQL, $con);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if($result){
        if($datPASS === $row['pass_exp']){
            $_SESSION['logged'] = true;
            $_SESSION['sexe'] = $row['sexe'];
            $_SESSION['type'] = $row['type_attachement'];
            header('Location: esm_questionnaire.php');
        }
        else{
            die('Vous n&#39;avez pas acces');
            }
    }
    }
```

Notice: Use of undefined constant sha512 - assumed 'sha512' in C:\wamp\www\Nouveaudossier\esm_connexion.php on line 12

this is the error i get if i have a wrong password or username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to change from:

```
$datPASS = hash(sha512, $datPASS);
```

To

```
$datPASS = hash('sha512', $datPASS);
```

**OR**, you need to define `sha512` as a constant first:

```
define('sha512', 'sha512');
```

<sup>But that seems a little silly, doesn't it?</sup>

Comment: Thank you :D fastest anwser i ever had on the internet. A good one none the less :D

Answer (score 0):

sha512 has to be between qoutes

Answer (score 0):

```
$datPASS = hash(sha512, $datPASS);
```

Replace it with

```
$datPASS = hash("sha512", $datPASS);
```

It will run eitherway though, lucky PHP is intelligent enough.